# What does the channel of an image mean?

Tags: image, opencv, channel

What does the "channel" of an image means? I have just starting using OpenCV and I don't really understand what are the channels of an image.

```
`package MatricesAndPixels;

import org.opencv.core.*;;

public class FirstMatrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        
        Mat image2 = new Mat(480,640,CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Mat image3 = new Mat(new Size(640,480), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Mat image = new Mat(new Size(3,3), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(new double [] {128,3,4}));

        System.out.println(image + "rows " + image.rows() 
        + " cols " + image.cols() + " elementsize " + image.elemSize());
        
    }
}`
```

In this example I print on the console the number of rows, columns and the element size. I don't know what does element size refers to. I have read that it returns the size of my image in bytes but I don't understand why is 3. I believe it is quite related to the channel.

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.10/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html#tutorial_how_to_scan_images_storing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single channel image has just one value at each [x,y] location in the image. That single value is normally the brightness of the image at that point, so it is a greyscale image.

A three channel image has three values at each [x,y] location in the image. The three values are normally the Red, Green and Blue intensities at that point, so it is an RGB image.

A four channel image is likely to be either `RGBA` (which is RGB and alpha/transparency), or CMYK (cyan, magenta, yellow and black colour separations) for print, or RGB + Depth from a Kinect-type of device.